# In Amazon AWS, how can I invoke a Lambda Function to execute only when an ELB's instance state transitions from InService to OutOfService?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudwatch

**Cases to consider**:

1. *Given:* An instance attached to an ELB with state InService

   *When:* Its state changes from InService to OutOfService

   *Then:* An AWS Lambda Function is invoked with the InstanceId as part of the event
2. *Given:* A fresh new instance, registered to an ELB for the first time

   *When:* It is still in the process of starting up (and therefore not yet reporting positive in health checks)

   *Then:* No AWS Lambda Function is invoked, since the desired state change has not occured

**Solutions I have attempted**

I set up a Lambda Function to poll a hard-coded list of ELBs every minute. It was successfully invoked for every instance with state: OutOfService. However this was not desirable, since it does not support the second case in the list of cases above.

I modified the health check function which reports back to the ELB. If health check failed, the ELB instance state of the instance from where it was being called. But this too was difficult to establish whether the instance was still starting up.

There are further options available to explore in the second solution but ideally I would prefer not to poll the ELB for information in order to trigger the Lambda Function. I would instead like the Lambda Function to recieve an event of such a transition (either through CloudWatch, SNS or something else if available).

Any insight into options I have not yet considered?

Comment: Eventually, the best way to do this would probably be with CloudWatch Events, but that service does not yet support ELB (per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html).

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly the route I thought I could take before starting. Only when I got to this part, did I realise functionality was missing.

Comment: Another potential option might be to use CloudWatch Alarms on ELB metrics. For example, raise an alarm on a HealthyHostCount of zero for N time periods which could cause an SNS notification to be sent to an SNS topic that then invokes a Lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree the polling for the status is not the right answer. One option to explore would be using cloudwatch alarms to trigger your lambda function.

Not 100% sure if there is a built in metric or if you would need to create a custom metric for this but from cloudwatch you can then trigger a SNS notification which in turn could trigger your lambda function.

Comment: Managed to get it to work from within the health checking endpoint. Now, whenever the ELB does a health check and it fails (if instance not in process of starting up), it checks to see if the ELB has its instance state marked as OutOfService.

The only drawback to this approach is if the health endpoint itself goes down (and the loadbalancer marks instance state to OutOfService) there is no way for the Lambda Function to be invoked.

I will try and replace what I have done with a custom metric. Got some reading to do to get that right.

Comment: Now that I have the health endpoint, which is targetted by the ELB, working correctly (also nice to have the poll frequency dynamic in relation to the ELB health check interval parameter), the only thing that won't perform the invocation of Lambda is if the ELB health endpoint itself is down.


I thought about a potential solution for this. Every time the health endpoint is reached it would send out an SNS notification to a topic unique to that instance. A CloudWatch alarm would trigger if latest message of that topic exceeds a time threshold. This CloudWatch alarm could do the invocation

Comment: But then I have to think about what if the machine is starting up and the healthpoint is not active yet... in this case, I do not want to trigger the lambda function.

Comment: So another option might be to try to use an application load balancer (should be pretty much the same set up) and you can use AWS config to trigger a lambda function.